# Where is Text.generate() in nltk3?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am working through a book on doing natural language processing in Python with nltk. I realize the book was written for nltk2, but decided to go with nltk3 since it is the current version. One of the examples calls for the Text.generate() function. I found that [the Text.generate() function does not exist in nltk3](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/text.html).

It turns out the demo for nltk.text is not aware that the Text.generate() function does not exist, as running

```
import nltk
nltk.text.demo()
```

raises an error since it attempts to use the Text.generate() function.

So was the Text.generate() function removed in nltk3? Or is it implemented somewhere else? I cannot find anything in the documentation mentioning it.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: I haven't. I think it's because nltk3 isn't complete yet, so they just haven't implemented Text.generate().